# Приоритет в css

Tags: css

Что в css приоритетнее? То, что указано в аттрибуте style="" или то, что с !important? Можно ли чем-то перекрыть style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!important` перебивает стили, вне зависимости от порядка подключения последних.

Вообще, порядок такой:

1. Стили из `<link rel="stylesheet">` и `<style type="text/css">` - применяются в первую очередь, в том порядке, в каком подключались в html;
2. Инлайновые стили (те, что в `style=""`) применяются вторыми;

`!important` же перебивает любые стили, неважно, где они были объявлены.

P.S. Перебить `!important` стиль может только такой же `!important`, только объявленный позже.

Comment: Или импортант с большим приоритетом. Больше вложение айдишек или классов